# Как вывести на сайт список пользователей онлайн по комнатам в TeamSpeak3

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Если сервер TS3 в котором сидят пользователи по комнатам. Как на сайте в реальном времени отображать всех пользователей онлайн по комнатам? Знаю, что для просмотра списка пользователей онлайн используется TeamSpeak 3 PHP Framework, но никак не могу найти как получить список пользователей по комнатам :( Желательно это сделать средствами языка php.

P.S.: Я знаю, что существуют модули для администрирования ТС и тому подобное. Но мне надо получить только список пользователей без всяких других наворотов.

**Обновление**

```
<?php


require_once("libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php");


$ts3_VirtualServer = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://username:password@127.0.0.1:10011/?server_port=9987");


$arr_ClientList = $ts3_VirtualServer->clientList();


print_r($arr_ClientList);

?>
```

Вот так можно получить список всех пользователей на сервере, но как по комнатам?

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, где-то в документации было                     $query = " 
                        SELECT 
                        username 
                        FROM users 
                        WHERE username = username "; .... т.е., предполагаю, что стоит попробовать сделать селект * фром юзерс, а потом условие с Id или названием комнаты. К сожалению, мне негде проверить